# Django index url is disabling api urls

Tags: django, angular, routes

integrating Angular with Django, server is receiving request from frontend but I can't handle them, because they doesn't reach target function

here is views.py:

```
class VView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer_class = UserSerializer

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny))
class Login(APIView):
   def post(self, request)
       return JsonRespone({"some":"data"}, status=200)
```

here are my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url('', index),
  url('user/login',Login.as_view()),
  url('user/registration',Login.as_view()),
]
```

and the thing is when send request now for `user/login` server doesn't respond with json as it should but when i comment out or delete my index url 
so I have:

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url('user/login',Login.as_view()),
  url('user/registration',Login.as_view()),
]
```

everything works fine I get responses from server when I am using Postman for that, or run frontend on another localhost, but the problem is that server doesn't render webpage, when I access it by localhost:8000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is happening coz you are confusing it with `path` and `url`.

```
 url('', index),
```

Here as you have given `''` in url it's not the correct way. And that's why it's not going to next subsequent patterns.

> **Solution-1:** Use proper `url` patterns with regular patterns using `^` and `$`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', index),
    url(r'^user/login/$',Login.as_view()),
    . . . . . 
]
```

> **Solution-2:** Use `path` if using `django>=2.0`.

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index),
    path('user/login',Login.as_view()),
    . . . . 
]
```

Comment: @Jake11, Please select the answer if it helped you. Thamks.